# Is it possible to return substring of column by char in python sqllite?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table holding strings with multiple "." sections.

e.g.,

```
"field1.field2.field3"
"field1.field2.field4"
"field1.field2.field5"
"field1.field2.field6"
"field40.field50.field60"
```

I would to query the table and return a distinct list of items up until the last ".".

In the above example the query should return

```
"field1.field2"
"field40.field50"
```

I am aware of `SELECT DISTINCT`, `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` but how do I combine all in the same query?

Comment: Please provide something to play with, close to a [mcve]. You can conveniently achieve that by showing a `.dump` from SQLite commandline tool for a suitably tailored toy database. Also please make an example of what you expect as a result.

Comment: The best answer, which probably you do not want to hear, is: "Change your database format, multiple fields in one string are the path to pain."

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has very poor string functionality.  One method that almost gets you there is:

```
select rtrim(col, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234456789')
```

You can then get what you want by doing:

```
select substr(col, 1, length(rtrim(lower(col), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234456789')) - 1)
```